# how does kernel code run on SMP machines

Tags: linux-kernel

How does the kernel code run on SMP machines? i know that module (driver) code can run on several processors\cores, but it this the same also for the core kernel code?

Comment: I'm not sure why this question was marked down by someone, seems un-fair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drivers are part of kernel, whether they are modular or built-in.

It is the scheduler that schedules Tasks[processes/threads] to each CPU/core.
Scheduler is a single Software entity that runs itself and runs other processes(kernel, its drivers, kernel threads, system calls, apps, ...).

Every process runs on the scheduler as per scheduling Algorithm under use.

It is the the scheduler that decides which process is supposed to be run on which CPU/core

Ex: Say Round Robin Scheduler, It keeps a time slice for every process that enters the "Ready Queue[RQ]". If the scheduler finds any processor/core idle and there are processes in RQ, it starts a timer to generate an interrupt when the timer reaches the time slice limit, and this interrupt will trigger the scheduler in the interrupt handler, and a process from the RQ will be given to the idle core for execution/running.

Thus, at any point of time, all the processors can be made to run the tasks, hence achieving high through put, if there are enough tasks to be run.